# Swift: Delegation protocol not setting UILabel properly

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, delegation

I have the following `Protocol`:

```
protocol SoundEventDelegate{
  func eventStarted(text:String)
}
```

which I call in this class:

```
class SoundEvent {
  var text:String
  var duration:Double
  init(text: String, duration: Double){
    self.text = text
    self.duration = duration
}

var delegate : SoundEventDelegate?

func startEvent(){
    delegate?.eventStarted(self.text)

}

  func getDuration() -> Double{
    return self.duration //TODO is this common practice?
  }

}
```

Which I have my `ViewController` conform to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SoundEventDelegate {
  //MARK:Properties
  @IBOutlet weak var beginButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var kleinGrossLabel: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  //DELEGATE method
  func eventStarted(text:String){
    kleinGrossLabel.text = text
  }

  //MARK: actions
  @IBAction func startImprovisation(sender: UIButton) {
    var s1:Sentence = Sentence(type: "S3")
    var s2:Sentence = Sentence(type: "S1")
    var newModel = SentenceMarkov(Ult: s1, Penult: s2)
    s1.start()
    beginButton.hidden = true
  } 
}
```

But when I run the app `kleinGrossLabel.text` does not change. Am I referring to the label in the wrong way? Or is it the way that I do delegation that is incorrect?

Here are links to the complete `Class` definitions of `Sentence` and `SentenceMarkov`

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9757d0ff00a4df7a29cb - `Sentence`

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/91d5d6a59b0c69cba915 - `SentenceMarkov`

Comment: getters like that are not common practice, as your getter and your variable have the same access control, so anywhere you could call that getter, you can just directly access the variable. They are useful if you want to have different levels of access control, such as a private var with a public getter

Comment: are you ever setting the delegate in your SoundEvent class to an actual object?

Comment: @WillM. yes see the first gist.`let event1 = SoundEvent(text: "klein", duration: DurationsArray[Int(durationIndex1)])` within the `Sentence` class

Comment: what part of that is setting the delegate property? ie. soundEvent.delegate = self

Comment: He didn't. All he did is creating an instance of `SoundEvent`.

Comment: @WillM. what is the getter and setter here? `eventStarted` is the setter? So I should just update the value of a variable that is accessible to both the `ViewController` and the `SoundEvent` such as a Singleton with a `String` var?

Comment: @Thalatta i was referring to this line `func getDuration() -> Double{
    return self.duration //TODO is this common practice?
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off it's not common practice to have a setter in swift. if you want to have a readonly property you can use `private(set) var propertyName` 
in other cases simply access the property like mentioned in the comment

Also i don't see a reason why you `eventArray` in sentence is of type `[SoundEvent?]` not `[SoundEvent]` as `SoundEvent`does not seem to have a failable initialiser

Like mentioned before you need to not only implement the SoundEventDelegate protocol but also set the delegate

the problem is that you can't really access the `SoundEventDelegate` from the viewcontroller because you instantiate the `SoundEvents` inside `Sentence`

```
var soundEventDelegate: SoundEventDelegate?
```

the easiest way to do this would be adding a `soundEventDelegate` property for sentence and setting it like this:

```
let s1:Sentence = Sentence(type: "S3")
let s2:Sentence = Sentence(type: "S1")
s1.soundEventDelegate = self
s2.soundEventDelegate = self
```

and inside sound you would need the set the delegate for every event to the `soundEventDelegate` of `Sentence`

you could do it like this:

```
var soundEventDelegate: SoundEventDelegate? = nil {
    didSet {
        eventArray.forEach({$0.delegate = soundEventDelegate})
    }
}
```

or write another initialiser that takes the delegate

hope this helps

p.s: you shouldn't inherit form NSObject in swift excepts it's really necessary

Comment: Quick question, how would I set my UILabel in the above context? It makes sense to have `Sentence` use the `SoudEventDelegate`, but how can I use the information of an `eventStart` to ultimately update my `UILabel`, when that is in `ViewController` and not `Sentence`?

Comment: do you instantiate ```SoundEvent``` directly inside of your ```VierviewController```? If not it should work this way by setting the sentences ```soundEventDelegate``` it should basically delegate the call directly from ```SoundEvent``` to the ```ViewController```

Comment: i created a playground where you can see the label changing on the right side https://gist.github.com/nafetswirth/e462c17bd9426a7caf8d

Answer (score 2):

You never set the delegate property. It's nil. It will never be called.

Comment: How is the delegate property set?

Comment: Somewhere you have an instance of your "SoundEvent" class. You need to set that instance's delegate property to the viewController instance that implements the delegate methods.

Comment: so `weak var delegate:ViewControllerDelegate?`

Comment: how do I refer to the instance of `ViewController` from the class?

Comment: Wherever in your virwController implementation that you create the SoundEvent instance. Do it there.

Comment: So I simply add `var delegate:SoundEventDelegate?` in my `startImprovisation` method in my `ViewController` class,  which will be referenced in `SoundEvent` ?

Comment: soundEvent.delegate = self ------ inside your vc implementation, where soundEvent is your SoundEvent instance.