# Updating UILabel.text with a variable belonging to a Singleton

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following `Singleton`

```
class SharingManager{
  var smallBigText : String = "KLANG!"
  static let sharedInstance = SharingManager()
}
```

I use it to set the text of the following `UILabel`

```
 @IBOutlet weak var kleinGrossLabel: UILabel!
```

I initialize its text here, in my `ViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.kleinGrossLabel.text = SharingManager.sharedInstance.smallBigText
}
```

I reset the `SharingManager.sharedInstance.smallBigText` in an instance method of my `SoundEvent` class:

```
   class SoundEvent {
    var text:String
    var duration:Double
    init(text: String, duration: Double){
      self.text = text
      self.duration = duration
    }

   func startEvent(){
    SharingManager.sharedInstance.smallBigText = self.text
   }

   func getDuration() -> Double{
      return self.duration 
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the `UILabel` text remains as "KLANG" and is never changed.

It should be changed when I call `startEvent` in the following function:

```
func playEvent(eventIndex : Int){
    if (eventIndex < 2){
        let currEvent = self.eventArray[eventIndex]
        currEvent?.startEvent()
        let nextIndex = eventIndex + 1
        //NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: SomeClass.self, selector: Selector("someClassMethod"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval((currEvent?.duration)!, target: self, selector: Selector("playEvent:"), userInfo: NSNumber(integer: nextIndex), repeats: false)
    }
    else if (eventIndex==2){
        self.eventArray[eventIndex]?.startEvent()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("sentenceDidFinish"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    else{
        //Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Which I call here in my `ViewController`

```
  var s1:Sentence = Sentence(type: "S3")
    s1.start()
```

Which in the `Sentence` class does this:

```
func start(){
    self.playEvent(0)

}
```

Somehow it breaks this flow of logic, or if the expected sequence of events IS executing, then it follows that I am not actually changing the `UILabel`'s text when I change the shared Singleton resource `var` `smallBigText`

For clarity here are all the main `.swift`

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07542f638fc5b9a3c4e9

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10f5f0deb03f9adc354c

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/94fda980836dc057b05b

Comment: Why don't you add some logging, break points or run it line by line in the debugger to see how your code actually executes and what the variable values are in different states?

Comment: Why do you expect the label's text to change, when you happen to change another variable?

Comment: you could turn that text into a property and use didSet to inform other classes that they need to update their labels. But seriously, run it through debugger

Comment: @PetahChristian good point, but how can I update the label's text without using a setter?

Comment: I suppose I could just set it directly in my other Object but that seems bad design. And when I used protocols, everyone told me that was a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188922/swift-delegation-protocol-not-setting-uilabel-properly?noredirect=1#comment58126580_35188922

Comment: @FruitAddict what text? `SoundEvent.text`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: no, you can turn the static variable into a property:  var smallBigText : String { return some_private_instance willSet {} didSet{} } and notify stuff when it happens. take a look at swift observable